# Linux desktop freezes regularly with audio skipping

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, desktop, troubleshooting

My desktop freezes randomly at times, and takes no input from either mouse or keyboard. If an audio track is playing (video, .mp3, etc.), the audio skips on the last sound or syllable heard, then goes silent, but after that happens I cannot enter any input until I restart my computer, after which the process may start over again.

My inxi specs:

> mothbyte-MS-7A15 ~ $ inxi -G
>       **Graphics:** Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Device 67df
>       **Display Server:** X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: ati,amdgpu (unloaded:
>       fbdev,vesa,radeon)
>       **Resolution:** 1920x1080@60.00hz
>       **GLX Renderer:** AMD Radeon RX 480 Graphics (POLARIS10 / DRM 3.15.0 /      4.12.0-041200-generic, LLVM 4.0.1)
>       **GLX Version:** 3.0 Mesa 17.3.0-devel

General system info:

> mothbyte-MS-7A15 ~ $ inxi -S
>   **System:**    Host: mothbyte-MS-7A15
>   **Kernel:** 4.12.0-041200-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
>   **Desktop:** Cinnamon 3.4.6
>   **Distro:** Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya

I suspect it has something to do with the drivers being un-updated, but I am not entirely sure. I built this computer as a rig and since it freezes somewhat often I think it might be an issue with my amd. I read that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> restarts Xorg, and I tested it out, made sure it worked, but I´m not sure when it freezes. If it is a driver issue, where can I find the repository for a much needed update?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your system is running out of free RAM and swapping. Check `free -h` output when the problem arises. Also, system monitoring programs like `htop` and `atop` can provide a wider glance at the current system load.